# How to access html file on a dss service with httpget operation

Tags: c#, html, http

I've created a custom dss service on MRDS 2008 and I need to stream an image when you access the service by *httpget operation* in a web browser(localhost:50000/dssservice).

The problem is that I have to refresh the web browser every time I need to reload a new image. The quid is, where do I get the html file/code so I can modify or add some javascript functions?